# PL/PgSQL store multiple records for processing

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

In PL/PgSQL - I can loop through records one at a time from the results of a query. How do I keep this set of retrieved records for later processing. As I won't be able to retrieve again. Is there any way to do this ? Like array of RECORDS ? (I am using postgres 8.3)

Answer (score 1):

PL/PgSQL has no persistent storage, beyond the lifetime of the procedure.

Within a procedure you could use an array of records, but appending to arrays is horribly inefficient in PostgreSQL - it results in a copy of the array being made. So appending n records one by one is nonlinearly expensive - somewhere between O(n log n) and O(n^2) I think. Using an array to of row-type to store the rows you wish to remember is likely to be a terrible idea.

Your best bet will be to `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` to store the records, then `INSERT` them into the temp table. There are some issues with temp tables inside PL/PgSQL in old PostgreSQL versions, but I *think* Pg 8.3 was the first version in which they were fixed so you should be OK. There's no namespacing though, so re-entrant (nested) executions of your procedure will have problems as the second will try to create an already existing temp table.

BTW, 8.3 is obsolete and unsupported. Start planning your upgrade.